# Why does my UITableView need to be below UIButton in the scene outliner

Tags: ios, uitableview, uibutton

I have an UIView with a UIButton and a UITableView. I constrained the UIButton (left, top, right, bottom) to (0,0,0,-) with a height of 50px. Below i constrained the UITableView (left, top, right, bottom) to (0,0,0,0) so that the screen would be filled with both views as such:

[image: Button above TableView]

In this case the UIButton is above the UITableView in the scene outliner:
[image: Scene Outliner (1)]

However whenever I reorder the view in the UIView so that the TableView is above the UIButton in the Scene Outliner it also moves my UITableViewCells but not my UITableView:

[image: Button below TableView]
[image]

The constraints are the same and nothing is moved except for the layering in the scene outliner. Why do my UITableViewCells move down whenever i place my UITableView above my UIButton?

Answer (score 0):

Interface Builder does that when "Adjust Scroll View Insets" in view controller attributes is checked.